# Jquery Ajax success function not fired for form submit/serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function SuccessFire() {
   var Datapost = document.forms[0].serialize();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: Datapost,
      url: "/Login/Authenticate",
      success: function (data) {
         alert("success");                       
      },
      error: function (data) {
         alert("failure")
      }
    });
}
```

Above code is not firing success function
Some more additional details
1. Authenticate is an action result
2. From Authenticate it is returned to Index action using "RedirectToAction"
3. Index action returns View

Comment: What is the issue, what error you see in the console? `$(document.forms[0]).serialize()`?

Comment: what type of data are you passing to your action method?

Comment: Both error and success functions are not firing

Comment: @user3080252 Check your console and see what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably looking for the jquery `serialize()` which can be executed on a jquery object and not on a raw DOM element (returned by `document.forms[0]`). So your script must be breaking before event making the ajax call.

Probably:

```
var Datapost = $(document.forms[0]).serialize();
```

Look at your browser console on what error you see.

Comment: I am able to see the serialized values in action method

Comment: @user3080252 Are you able to see them and are you returning from your action at all? WHat is the http status code you see.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check in the browser debug mode to see if you recieve http status = 200

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the response is a redirect (Http Code 302)?